# Pandas - Get First n-Rows That Consists of X Percentage of Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is the result of a group-by, already sorted by value (highest to lowest) within each group:

```
Group Record ID Value
A       1        10
        2        8
        3        6
B       4        9
        5        7
        6        5
...
Z       97       11
        98       9
        99       7
10000 rows x 1 columns
```

I want to be able to find the top n rows whose value add up to x% percent of the group total.

Basically, I am trying to explore and determine the minimum amount of records needed to cover the biggest amount of total data (measured by value). For example, perhaps the top 800 records have their corresponding value add up to 90% of the total value, whereas the 801th record can only contribute to 0.5% more, hence 800 will be the cutoff count here.

Is there an elegant way to do that?

Comment: You provide several thresholds (90% total, +0.5% cumulative delta), but not a definitive one. Both are not present in your example data. Can you include a [MRE]?

Comment: Hi @MichaelSzczesny, I was referring to the group value total. For example, group A's value total is 10+8+6=24, so the record 1,2,3 will have their percentage of total be 41,67%, 33.3%, and 25%, respectively. If I were to ask, I want the top few records that give me 75% of total value, in this case, I will get a dataframe consists of record 1 and 2, because their percentage add up to 75%. I hope this makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the below codes to generate two cumsum fields and got the data I can start exploring.

```
value_pcts = table.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum()))
table = pd.concat([table, value_pcts], axis=1)
table = table_new.reset_index()
table['value_cumsum'] = table.groupby(['A'])['value'].cumsum()
table['pct_cumsum'] = table.groupby(['A'])['percentage'].cumsum()
```

I still wonder if there is a neater way.